# python.sql in Zeppelin error: NameError: name 'pd' is not defined

Tags: docker

New to install zeppelin and girdb in docker

```
git clone https://github.com/roenschg/griddb-zeppelin-quikstart.git
cd griddb-zeppelin-quikstart/
docker-compose build docker-compose up
```

**Connecting to GridDB**

```
import jaydebeapi

conn = jaydebeapi.connect("com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.Driver",
                           "jdbc:gs://griddb:20001/defaultCluster/public?notificationMember:127.0.0.1:20001",
                           ["admin", "admin"],
                          "/usr/share/java/gridstore-jdbc-4.5.0.jar",)
```

For this, access your GridDB table using an SQL query with one of the pandas functions to feed the data directly into a dataframe:

```
*sql = ("SELECT * FROM iotdata WHERE TIMESTAMP(timestamp) < TIMESTAMP_ADD(DAY, NOW(), -5)")
iotdf = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn)*
```

Output

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
*NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-ac103e118435> in <module>
      1 sql = ("SELECT * FROM iotdata WHERE TIMESTAMP(timestamp) < TIMESTAMP_ADD(DAY, NOW(), -5)")
----> 2 iotdf = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn)
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined*
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you import and declare pandas as 'pd' at the top of your file?